# How can I fix the price of a quote?

Tags: shipping-methods, quote, discount

Is there any way to create a "price freeze" that stops the price of items in a quote from changing? Ideally discounts still need to be calculated while shipping price would also be frozen.

**Edit:**
My definition of "freeze" is that the price should not be updated based on changes to prices of the items contained.

Comment: I think you should define the "freeze" more in order for someone to be able to answer your question. Also what is the purpose of this? If you could explain how and why then answering the question would be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Magento gives the admin to override quote item prices in adminhtml. This uses the columns `custom_price` and `original_custom_price`. Both must be populated, otherwise, a cart refresh will reset your prices. I believe this will ignore other discounts and promotional rules.

Set your "freeze price" to `custom_price` and `original_custom_price` in the quote table to the price you want.

Comment: Thanks, this does 90% of what I need.

Any idea how to similarly fix the shipping price to what was initially offered?

Comment: @Li1t, for shipping.. I think you can create a custom shipping method for which you can set the cost. You can try to hijack one of the default methods, but I'm not sure how that works. Check out the classes that extend `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to fix the price of a shipment. It's not exactly the simplest solution. There may also be un-nessecary code. It does, however, seem to work. I had to create a dummy shipping rate and prevent the address from collecting further shipping rates.

Where the prices are being fixed:

```
$rate = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_address_rate');
$rate->setCode($method)
    ->setCarrier('')
    ->setCarrierTitle('')
    ->setMethod('')
    ->setMethodTitle('')
    ->setMethodDescription($description)
    ->setPrice($amount);
$shipAddress->addShippingRate($rate);
$shipAddress->setShippingOverride(true);
$shipAddress->setShippingDescription($description);
$shipAddress->setShippingMethod($method);
```

In an overridden version of Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address:

```
public function collectShippingRates()
{
    if (!$this->getCollectShippingRates()) {
        return $this;
    }
    if($this->getShippingOverride()) {
        return $this;
    } else {
        return parent::collectShippingRates();
    }
}
public function requestShippingRates(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract $item = null)
{
    if($this->getShippingOverride()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return parent::requestShippingRates($item);
    }
}
```